# Как сделать отчёт в Excel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, excel

Bозможно ли сохранить часть бд в виде отчёта в excel? Если да, то скиньте примеры или ссылки на них.

Comment: Это две задачи: 1 - sql запросом получить данные из базы; 2 - записать их в файл excel. Для второй части есть библиотеки, например xlwt или openpyxl. Для первой части - все зависит от того что за таблицы у вас в базе.

Comment: Для формирования Excel-отчета можно ещё глянуть на `xlsxwriter`.